# MariaDB pegging cpu at 100%, need some help please

Tags: mariadb, configuration

I am having issues with a server and have had issues for awhile but finally getting around to trying to fix it.

When I run top, I see that 1 of the cores is near 100% and it usually never drops below 95%.

```
%Cpu(s):  0.3 us,  0.2 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.5 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
```

I have 64gb ram:

```
KiB Mem : 65748964 total,   494008 free,   985284 used, 64269672 buff/cache
KiB Swap: 33521660 total, 33400828 free,   120832 used. 63915376 avail Mem
```

Here is my `my.cnf` (trimmed to remove anything #)

```
[server]
[mysqld]
max_connections = 50
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
skip-name-resolve
sort_buffer_size        = 128M
tmp_table_size          = 256MM
key_buffer_size         = 128M
max_allowed_packet      = 256M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 16
myisam_recover_options  = BACKUP
query_cache_limit       = 128M
query_cache_size        = 0
query_cache_type        = 0
performance_schema = OFF
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
expire_logs_days        = 10
max_binlog_size   = 100M
character-set-server  = utf8mb4
collation-server      = utf8mb4_general_ci
[embedded]
[mariadb]
[mariadb-10.1]
```

I did run mysql tuner and here was the output:

```
[--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
[OK] Logged in using credentials passed on the command line
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 10.1.34-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture
-------- Log file Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Log file: /var/log/mysql/error.log(0B)
[OK] Log file /var/log/mysql/error.log exists
[OK] Log file /var/log/mysql/error.log is readable.
[!!] Log file /var/log/mysql/error.log is empty
[OK] Log file /var/log/mysql/error.log is smaller than 32 Mb
[OK] /var/log/mysql/error.log doesn't contain any warning.
[OK] /var/log/mysql/error.log doesn't contain any error.
[--] 0 start(s) detected in /var/log/mysql/error.log
[--] 0 shutdown(s) detected in /var/log/mysql/error.log
-------- Storage Engine Statistics -----------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +Aria +CSV +InnoDB +MEMORY +MRG_MyISAM +MyISAM +PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA +SEQUENCE
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 2.1M (Tables: 49)
[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 31.4G (Tables: 339)
[OK] Total fragmented tables: 0
-------- Analysis Performance Metrics --------------------------------------------------------------
[--] innodb_stats_on_metadata: OFF
[OK] No stat updates during querying INFORMATION_SCHEMA.
-------- Security Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------
[OK] There are no anonymous accounts for any database users
[OK] All database users have passwords assigned
[--] There are 618 basic passwords in the list.
-------- CVE Security Recommendations --------------------------------------------------------------
[OK] NO SECURITY CVE FOUND FOR YOUR VERSION
-------- Performance Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 131d 22h 10m 38s (7B q [644.089 qps], 2M conn, TX: 1414G, RX: 556G)
[--] Reads / Writes: 96% / 4%
[--] Binary logging is disabled
[--] Physical Memory     : 62.7G
[--] Max MySQL memory    : 6.7G
[--] Other process memory: 989.5M
[--] Total buffers: 424.0M global + 128.8M per thread (50 max threads)
[--] P_S Max memory usage: 0B
[--] Galera GCache Max memory usage: 0B
[OK] Maximum reached memory usage: 3.6G (5.68% of installed RAM)
[OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 6.7G (10.69% of installed RAM)
[OK] Overall possible memory usage with other process is compatible with memory available
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (216/7B)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 50% (25/50)
[OK] Aborted connections: 2.03%  (52376/2580658)
[OK] Query cache is disabled by default due to mutex contention on multiprocessor machines.
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (0 temp sorts / 3M sorts)
[OK] No joins without indexes
[!!] Temporary tables created on disk: 27% (83K on disk / 304K total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 99% (667 created / 2M connections)
[!!] Table cache hit rate: 3% (606 open / 15K opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 5% (874/16K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 99% (7B immediate / 7B locks)
-------- Performance schema ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Performance schema is disabled.
[--] Memory used by P_S: 0B
[--] Sys schema isn't installed.
-------- ThreadPool Metrics ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] ThreadPool stat is enabled.
[--] Thread Pool Size: 8 thread(s).
[--] Using default value is good enough for your version (10.1.34-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)
-------- MyISAM Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[OK] Key buffer used: 100.0% (134M used / 134M cache)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 128.0M/9.2G
[OK] Read Key buffer hit rate: 99.9% (53B cached / 33M reads)
[!!] Write Key buffer hit rate: 50.0% (515M cached / 257M writes)
-------- InnoDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] InnoDB is enabled.
[--] InnoDB Thread Concurrency: 0
[OK] InnoDB File per table is activated
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 128.0M/2.1M
[!!] Ratio InnoDB log file size / InnoDB Buffer pool size (75 %): 48.0M * 2/128.0M should be equal 25%
[!!] InnoDB buffer pool <= 1G and Innodb_buffer_pool_instances(!=1).
[--] InnoDB Buffer Pool Chunk Size not used or defined in your version
[OK] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 99.27% (76133 hits/ 76689 total)
[!!] InnoDB Write Log efficiency: 14.75% (63 hits/ 427 total)
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (0 waits / 364 writes)
-------- AriaDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] AriaDB is enabled.
[OK] Aria pagecache size / total Aria indexes: 128.0M/1B
[OK] Aria pagecache hit rate: 99.9% (87M cached / 83K reads)
-------- TokuDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] TokuDB is disabled.
-------- XtraDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] XtraDB is disabled.
-------- Galera Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera is disabled.
-------- Replication Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera Synchronous replication: NO
[--] No replication slave(s) for this server.
[--] Binlog format: STATEMENT
[--] XA support enabled: ON
[--] Semi synchronous replication Master: Not Activated
[--] Semi synchronous replication Slave: Not Activated
[--] This is a standalone server
-------- Recommendations ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    When making adjustments, make tmp_table_size/max_heap_table_size equal
    Reduce your SELECT DISTINCT queries which have no LIMIT clause
    Increase table_open_cache gradually to avoid file descriptor limits
    Read this before increasing table_open_cache over 64: http://bit.ly/1mi7c4C
    Read this before increasing for MariaDB https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/optimizing-table_open_cache/
    This is MyISAM only table_cache scalability problem, InnoDB not affected.
    See more details here: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=49177
    This bug already fixed in MySQL 5.7.9 and newer MySQL versions.
    Beware that open_files_limit (16364) variable
    should be greater than table_open_cache (2000)
    Performance schema should be activated for better diagnostics
    Consider installing Sys schema from https://github.com/mysql/mysql-sys
    Before changing innodb_log_file_size and/or innodb_log_files_in_group read this: http://bit.ly/2wgkDvS
Variables to adjust:
    tmp_table_size (> 256M)
    max_heap_table_size (> 16M)
    table_open_cache (> 2000)
    performance_schema = ON enable PFS
    innodb_log_file_size should be (=16M) if possible, so InnoDB total log files size equals to 25% of buffer pool size.
    innodb_buffer_pool_instances (=1)
```

If you have made it this far, thank you and huge thanks if you can help me.  My only other option was a new box but if it's the config, I would only see the same results eventually.

Comment: Why do you think that one core at 100% utilization is an issue? Have you tried to apply suggestions from mysqltuner?

Comment: The load is running at about 1.5 and then I saw that 99.5 id

I have made changes over time per mysqltuner but it didn't seem to make a difference.  I figured I would post here before I made the ones its suggesting now in case there is something that I am missing that is glaringly obvious.

Comment: OP: Sorry, I do not understand your comment. Regardless, there's no magic parameter that reduces CPU utilization. You need to identify _statements_ that consume CPU. The usual suspects are: those in the slow log; those that don't use indexes; those that have to sort and especially those that _spill_ sorts.

Comment: High CPU is almost always due to a query.  Simply doing `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` may spot the query.  Provide us with the query and `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for any table(s) that it uses.  The solution may be simply the addition of a composite index or reformulating the query.

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
# cores of your MySQL Host server 
From SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Please post additional information requested Nov 20, 2019 to allow server workload tuning analysis and suggestions preparation for your instance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> - Reduce your SELECT DISTINCT queries which have no LIMIT clause
> - Increase table_open_cache gradually to avoid file descriptor limits
> - Read this before increasing table_open_cache over 64: http://bit.ly/1mi7c4C
> - Read this before increasing for MariaDB https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/optimizing-table_open_cache/
> - This is MyISAM only table_cache scalability problem, InnoDB not affected.
> - See more details here: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=49177
> - This bug already fixed in MySQL 5.7.9 and newer MySQL versions.

just a short task-list for you.

Check mariadb for updates that correct the mentioned bug-report
follow the mentioned guidelines to increase table_open_cache.

Consider switching to InnoDB - in my own experience there is usually nothing that MyISAM can that InnoDB can't do - aside the various advantages like foreign key references on database level, automated index' on foreign key references, more intelligent table locks for various operations and so on..

And most optimizations for database code done by oracle went purely into InnoDB

Comment: Thanks Eagle275.  I am converting right now to innodb.  Slowly to make sure nothing breaks and I made some changes to my.cnf too.

Comment: @user1664405 To prepare for getting your tables to INNODB, in your configuration consider using A) innodb_buffer_pool_size=32G B) innodb_buffer_pool_instances=16; C) innodb_lru_scan_depth=100 to accommodate nearly all the data space required in the buffer pool. Further adjustments will be needed as you near the end of changing the MyISAM tables to INNODB. Let us know as you make progress, how many tables are left to change with a WEEKLY fresh MySQLTuner complete report, please.